# Magento 2 refresh checkout page clearing the cart

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart

In checkout page, if the page got refreshed on the browser (F5) or by any other way like re visiting the checkout link, it is clearing the items from the cart

Answer (score 0):

Check the latest releases, such as 2.2.6 and you will see this is already addressed.